# React Native Mutation using GraphQL Won't hit Backend, returns 400 error instead

Tags: react-native, graphql, mutation

I'm using GraphQL for a React Native Project, and most of my mutations work fine but one of them just refuses to work. The mutation must work on the backend, because when I try running the mutation through Apollo Studio it works. I copied the exact code from Apollo Studio-- which works, into my `operations.js` file so that the mutation in question looks like so...

```
const DRIVERCREATECOLLISIONACCIDENT = gql`
mutation Mutation($accidentId: String!, $specificPictures: JSON!, $contactInfo: JSON!, $collisionReport: JSON!, $extraInfo: String!) {
  driverCreateCollisionAccident(accidentId: $accidentId, specific_pictures: $specificPictures, contact_info: $contactInfo, collision_report: $collisionReport, extra_info: $extraInfo) {
    id
  }
}
`
```

and the mutation in my Native Code looks like this...

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
        handleMutation().then( (resolved) => {
            console.log(resolved)
        })
    }

    const handleMutation = async () => {
        await createCollision({
            variables: {
                accidentId: collisionData.accidentId,
                specific_pictures: collisionData.specific_pictures,
                contact_info: collisionData.contact_info,
                collision_report: collisionData.collision_report,
                extra_info: collisionData.extra_info,
                accident: {
                    connect: {
                        id: collisionData.accidentId
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

NOTE that I have `console.log` statements that prove that `collisionData` holds exactly the data I need it to. I have numerous `console.log` statements in the backend as well, but none of them get hit at all, which tells me that the mutation isnt even getting hit in the backend and a 400 error is just thrown back right away instead. What gives? This syntactically looks just like the rest of my working mutations

Answer (score 0):

The variables when calling the mutation do not match the variables in the gql statement.

Please try this:

```
const DRIVERCREATECOLLISIONACCIDENT = gql`
  mutation Mutation($accidentId: String!, $specific_pictures: JSON!, $contact_info: JSON!, $collision_report: JSON!, $extra_info: String!) {
    driverCreateCollisionAccident(accidentId: $accidentId, specific_pictures: $specific_pictures, contact_info: $contact_info, collision_report: $collision_report, extra_info: $extra_info) {
    id
  }
}
```

Also, double check the schema for your mutation, and make sure the input variables are matching in your gql statement.

I do not see where `accident` is passed in your mutation as well.